# Json to java object android?

Tags: android, json, gson

Can anyone please help me to convert this JSON to Java Object. I usually use GSON, but it seem this time it is not working for me. The problem is that I want to create an Object that contains

```
Class JsonGotText{
String status; 
List<Object> result;
}
```

But all the Object in List is all difference properties... So I don know how to do to let Gson Map it correctly

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "1346053628": {
      "type": "default",
      "decorated_time": 1346053628,
      "guidOwner": 13716,
      "friendGuid": 3264,
      "action_type": "friend",
      "summary": " is now a friend with ",
      "annotation": null,
      "group": ""
    },
    "1346051675": {
      "type": "event",
      "decorated_time": 1346051675,
      "guidOwner": 90,
      "title": null,
      "action_type": "event_relationship",
      "summary": "river:event_relationship:object:event",
      "annotation": null,
      "group": ""
    },
    "1346048488": {
      "type": "event",
      "decorated_time": 1346048488,
      "guidOwner": 90,
      "title": null,
      "action_type": "event_relationship",
      "summary": "river:event_relationship:object:event",
      "annotation": null,
      "group": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the "result" object in your json should be an array.

Comment: Yeah I think so, But the problem is in the array that store difference object... Do u have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Class JsonGotText{
String status; 
HashMap<String, Object> result;
}
```

If performance is not key criteria here. You better use 'JSONObject' without worrying the structure of JSON String.

---

Ideally, you should write a POJO. Say `EventPOJO` that has attributes same as as each result object holds and then make the Java class as

```
Class JsonGotText{
  String status; 
  HashMap<String, EventPOJO> result;
}
```

you may have to use a type token [see here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types), but will save your efforts later.

**Update**
It seems the sentence above sounds confusing. Here is clarification what I wanted `EventPOJO` to represent to. The EventPOJO will represents things like

```
{
      "type": "event",
      "decorated_time": 1346048488,
      "guidOwner": 90,
      "title": null,
      "action_type": "event_relationship",
      "summary": "river:event_relationship:object:event",
      "annotation": null,
      "group": ""
    }
```

---

**Update1** @LalitPoptani asked for exact working code. Here it is!

Here is an working example:

```
public class Test {

    private static String json = 
            "{"+
                      "\"status\": 0,"+
                      "\"result\": {"+
                        "\"1346053628\": {"+
                          "\"type\": \"default\","+
                          "\"decorated_time\": 1346053628,"+
                          "\"guidOwner\": 13716"+
                        "},"+
                        "\"1346051675\": {"+
                          "\"type\": \"event\","+
                          "\"decorated_time\": 1346051675,"+
                          "\"guidOwner\": 90"+
                        "},"+
                        "\"1346048488\": {"+
                          "\"type\": \"event\","+
                          "\"decorated_time\": 1346048488,"+
                          "\"guidOwner\": 90"+
                        "}"+
                      "}" +
             "}";

    public static class Event{
        String type;
        Long decorated_time;
        Integer guidOwner;
    }

    public static class JSON{
        Integer status;
        HashMap<Long, Event> result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println("JSON: " + json);
        JSON j = gson.fromJson(json, JSON.class);
        for(Entry<Long, Event> e: j.result.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue().guidOwner);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LalitPoptani well, results will go in hashMap :) the keys will be the keys of teh map, and POJO represents what keys are mapped to. I am not saying to have those ints to be attributes. Did you the JsonGotObject again?

Comment: 2 things. 1. If he uses JSONObject, he could just do getJSONObject("result"); and then get Keys and iterate into the keys and get JSONObject that represents his event details. 2. If he used Gson, then he will just get the JsonGotText object and iterate in hashmp. Easy?

Comment: @LalitPoptani 1. I hate spoon feeding people, they should learn. 2. I do not get paid for it. So, it's upto me, not you, to detail as much as **I** want. 3. OP asks doubt NOT you. 4. You could have answered! 5. They could better hire me at Google. :)

Comment: Well, I didn't say you to spoon feed. Your previous answer was not clear at all. So, I just asked you to add a small psuedo code that would be better for the OP to understand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15843/discussion-between-nishant-and-lalit-poptani)